# How to do point cloud stitching in Python?

Tags: python, point-clouds, image-stitching

I am trying to use four point clouds files and stich them together to form one 3D image.

I have tried to search online on how to do something similar to that, however, I did not find anything that was quite good enough for me. How should I do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, ideally you want to compute camera pose used to capture each point cloud file and then use those pose to transform each pointcloud. See https://youtu.be/f9dCo6SlCFU?t=845 where pointcloud coming from 3 different cameras are first transformed using their pose and then merged together. For computing pose, you can use aruco markers/charuco board/etc.